# How can I make sure a program is killed when VPN is running?

Tags: command-line, scripts, vpn, process, killall

There is a program that I need to *not* have running whenever my VPN is running. I don't want to resort to closing it manually every time, because I might forget sometime.

I would like to guarantee that they are not running at the same time. This could mean kill one when the other starts, or prevent one from opening when the other is open.

Comment: How do you start `vpn`; GUI or cli?

Comment: @JacobVlijm GUI from the network indicator

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, thanks for your answer! I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but I'll report back right away when I get an opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Options to prevent an application to run while VPN is running

There are several options to prevent running an application when `VPN` is running:

- Combine the command to open `VPN` with the command to kill the application
- Run a small background script to kill the application if `VPN` runs

Although the first option seems to be the cleanest, there are a few reasons to choose the second:

- The application could very well be killed whenever `VPN` starts, but that would not prevent the application to run accidentally afterwards.
- Since you mention you start `VPN` from the GUI, You would have to change the way how to start `VPN`, to combine it with killing the application.

*So...*

Below a small background script to make sure the application is not running at the same time as `VPN`.

#### How to check if VPN is running

To check if `VPN` is running or not, the answer checks if the string `<OpenVPNserver>` is present in the output of the command

```
route
```

or not. Please check if this is the case first. If not, we need to find another identifying string.

#### How the script works

- Once per two seconds, the script checks if `VPN` is running by checking if the sctring `<OpenVPNserver>` is in the output of:

  ```
  route
  ```
- (Only) if so, the script checks if the application is running, with the command:

  ```
  pgrep <application>
  ```

  and kills it if so, with the command:

  ```
  kill <pid>
  ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import time

app = sys.argv[1]

def check_ifrunning():
    # check if connection is up or down
    get_routeinfo = subprocess.check_output(["route"]).decode("utf-8")
    if "<OpenVPNserver>" in get_routeinfo:
        try:
            pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", app]).decode("utf-8").strip()
            subprocess.Popen(["kill", pid])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    check_ifrunning()
```

#### How to use

1. First open a terminal, run VPN like you are used to and check if the string `<OpenVPNserver>` occurs in the output of the command

   ```
   route
   ```
2. If so, Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `prevent_run.py`
3. Test- run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/prevent_run.py <processname>
   ```

   (I tested it for example with the command `python3 /home/jacob/Bureaublad/prevent_run.py gedit`)
4. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/prevent_run.py <processname>
   ```

#### Note

As usual (and like it should be), the script is *extremely* light weight. It add no noticeable "background noies" whatsoever.

Comment: Slight nitpick..`Popen` does not return `CalledProcessError`..to be more robust perhaps you should add `Popen` outside or use `check_call` instead

Comment: @heemayl I don't want it to return a `CalledProcessError` (and it should not), that is what `subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", app]).decode("utf-8").strip()` does if the process is not running. If so, the `subprocess.Popen(["kill", pid])` is jumped over and does not execute. This is really the best way, saves energy in the loop. Robust as it gets.

Comment: Got that.. But I think it would make more sense to keep it out of `try` snippet to keep `try` terse and to the precise..

Comment: @heemayl your suggestion would imply an additional `else:` to the `try/except`. In this case, since the `subprocess.Popen()` line is rarely reached, and then only a single time, it actually is no part of the loop in practice. I'd rather have the simplicity in coding and keep it in one step, then force verbosity to only satisfy the idea.

Comment: No problem.. Here's my upvote ..

Comment: Thanks! It does indeed work, though I had to change `<OpenVPNserver>` to `vpn`. The only thing I'm worried about is how fast I need it to be.  I don't have a sense of these things -- would you expect it to put any strain on my computer if I decrease the sleep to, say, 0.1 seconds?

Comment: Hi @Hatshepsut , I cannot judge the importance of the speed. I tried to set it to `0.1`, it then raises my processor's idle "occupation" with appr. 2%, which is acceptable in my opinion if you aren't  running a lot more background processes.